# How can I remove a red line when I use to_string?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

```
template<typename T, int>
class Array {
    int x;
public:
    Array() { }
    int& operator [](int idx) { return idx; }
    operator string() const { return "("string"s + to_string(x))"; }
};
```

int main()

```
    Array<string, 10> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            a[i] = "string"s + to_string(i);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            cout << a[i] << endl;
```

A red line is under the "string"s. how can I remove that?

Comment: Did you `#include <string>`? What IDE are you using?

Comment: Do you have a `using std::string_literals` in your code?

Comment: Your quotes are strangely balanced, `"("string "s + to_string(x))"`.

Comment: `int& operator [](int idx)` is incompatible with `a[i] = "string"s + to_string(i);`.

Comment: What is your IDE? Does the code compile?

Comment: This problem is likely the result of a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The following compiles fine:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, int>
class Array {
    int x;
public:
    Array() { }
    int& operator [](int idx) { return idx; }
    operator string() const { return "string"s + to_string(x); }
};

int
main()
{
    Array<bool, 42> a;
    return 0;
}
```

I had to change:

```
"("string"s + to_string(x))"
```

to

```
"string"s + to_string(x)
```

Or it could be (as stated in the comments)

```
"("s + to_string(x) + ")"s
```

Just depends on what your intent was.

Comment: Or `return "("s + to_string(x) + ")"s;`? For me, it looks like input of OP has been mixed with auto-completion of IntelliSense. I don't hate it enough to switch it off but sometimes it makes annoying replacements. I sometimes ask myself whether the "Intelli" wasn't a bit over-optimistic... ;-)

Comment: agreed... could be that too. Hard to tell what the OP was looking for